# Formatar string no PHP

Tags: php, string, formatação

Vi alguns exemplos aqui no **StackOverflow**, mas eu simplesmente não consegui.

Preciso formatar essa string:

```
'personalization_id="v1_i8b1bAFy7m6K+j3TseNGDw=="'
```

Se eu usar um `$cookie = explode('=', $cookie);` ela fica assim:

```
0 => string 'personalization_id' (length=18)
1 => string '"v1_IQfbwu+xRVCTQaUk9sGfBQ' (length=26)
2 => string '' (length=0)
3 => string '"' (length=1)
```

Repare que os **==** no final sumiram, eu preciso que eles ficam lá, só = depois do nome do `cookie` suma.

Qual a solução?

Meu código:

```
if (preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie: \s*([^;]*)/mi', $response, $matches)) {
    foreach ($matches[1] as $cookie) {
        $cookie = explode('=', $cookie);
        var_dump($cookie);
    }
}
```

### Editado

```
function getCSRF() {
    $request = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($request, [
            CURLOPT_URL                         => 'https://twitter.com/',
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST       => 'GET',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
            CURLOPT_HEADER                  => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER          => [
                'user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
            ]
        ]
    );
    $response = curl_exec($request);
    curl_close($request);

    if (preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie: \s*([^;]*)/mi', $response, $matches)) {
        foreach ($matches[1] as $cookie) {
            $cookie = explode('=', $cookie);
            var_dump($cookie);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Não pode ser apenas '$cookie = explode('="', $cookie);' ?

Comment: Não ele me retorna apenas um **=** no final e os restos dos `cookies` não serão um `array`.

Comment: São varios cookies na string ? eles serão sempre os mesmos ?

Comment: Sim são varios com chaves e valores diferentes, mais um exemplo: `fm=0`

Comment: Mas os nomes dos cookies vão ser os mesmos correto ? não acho que tenha como explodir, acho que vais ter que usar preg_math um pra cada cookie, mas isso só vai funcionar se os nomes forem sempre os mesmos

Comment: Aaa tem que ter um jeito. `twid="u=123456789"` este também remove **=** depois do **u**

Comment: Editei a pergunta o ultimo código basta apenas executar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei está correto esta forma, porém acho que minha lógica está correta, se está bom pra mim, então creio eu que respondo minha pergunta:

```
if (preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie: \s*([^;]*)/mi', $response, $matches)) {
        foreach ($matches[1] as $cookie) {
            $cookie = explode('=', $cookie);
            $key = (!empty($cookie[0])) ? $cookie[0] : '';
            $value = (!empty($cookie[1])) ? $cookie[1] : '';
            $value .= (isset($cookie[2])) ? '==' : '';
            $value .= (isset($cookie[3])) ? $cookie[3] : '';

            $obj->{$key} = $value;
            $obj->cookies .= $key . '=' . $obj->{$key} . '; '; 
        }
    }
```